# f:convertDateTime not being strict in pattern match?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a f:convertDateTime with a pattern of mm/dd/yyyy. However, people are able to enter 2/19/78 and it would be 0078 rather then 1978 or 2078. I want to force people to enter in all 4 digits.

I tried using a regexPattern validator, but that is complaining because it wants a string and not a Date object. Seems that the converters fire first and validators validate the converted value?

I guess I could write a custom converter or validator, but this seems like such a simple thing I figure I'm doing something wrong.

The javadocs for the convertor say it is strict in matching the pattern, but I'm not seeing that?

Any ideas or suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only strict for days/months, not for years. Here's an extract of relevance from [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which `<f:convertDateTime>` is using under the covers:

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

It's by design indeed not possible to fire validators before converters. Essentially, this one should have thrown a `ConverterException` because the input is not in the proper format. I'd create a custom converter which validates the pattern beforehand. Something like this:

```java
@FacesConverter("validatingPatternDateTimeConverter")
public class ValidatingPatternDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        String regex = getMandatoryAttribute(component, "validateRegex");
        String pattern = getMandatoryAttribute(component, "convertPattern");

        if (value != null && !value.matches(regex)) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Invalid date, must be in pattern %s", pattern)));
        }

        setPattern(pattern);
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        setPattern(getMandatoryAttribute(component, "convertPattern"));
        return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
    }

    private String getMandatoryAttribute(UIComponent component, String name) {
        String value = (String) component.getAttributes().get(name);

        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("<f:attribute name=\"%s\"> is missing.", name));
        }

        return value;
    }

}
```

which is to be used as follows:

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:converter converterId="validatingPatternDateTimeConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="validateRegex" value="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" />
    <f:attribute name="convertPattern" value="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```